# What can I do with a Java Number?

Tags: java, numbers

A function from a library returns a `Number`. I can't convert it to anything usable ("cannot convert from Number to int") and can't print it using `String.format`. How do I handle the `Number`?

Comment: `Number` has methods to return values. `intValue()`, `longValue()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. But why can't it be casted if those functions exist anyway?

Comment: Because you don't know the dynamic type of the underlying object. The `xValue()` methods return the primitive type value.

Comment: Number: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't convert it to anything usable

Of course you can!

```
void doSomething(Number myNumber) {
    int intNumber = myNumber.intValue();
    double dblNumber = myNumber.doubleValue();
    // Now do something useful
}
```

The idea behind the `Number` class is to give a common superclass to the built-in numeric types. It gives you more flexibility in passing the numbers around, so that the decision on what type to use could be postponed until the moment when the numeric value is needed.

This becomes especially useful when the code for the data retrieval is separate from the code that consumes the numeric data, because the retrieval code can operate in terms of untyped numbers, without concerns about the specific type.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- cast it to its underlying type
- convert it to a primitive type
- toString() it with. e.g. String.format("%s", number);

In general it is not that useful IMHO.

I prefer to use `double` as a "super primitive" type. or BigDecimal/BigInteger if that is not a option.

> But why can't it be casted if those functions exist anyway?

`Number` is a reference to an object, not an object.  You can change the type of the reference, but you cannot use cast to alter or create a new object.

Comment: I despise doubles. There's too many caveats to IEEE. The performance difference between BigDecimal and double is often neglibile in these times.

Comment: @Cruncher: For small decimal numbers, you might be right.  As the numbers get bigger or the calculations get more involved, though, the weaknesses of both types become obvious.  The performance of `double` doesn't change much at all, but rounding errors increase.  `BigDecimal` retains more precision, but can get dog slow -- and being an immutable object, tends to increase GC pressure.  It's all about the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Cruncher the performance difference is about 100x.  This doesn't always matter compared to the cost of introducing a bug, but IMHO you are just as likely to introduce bugs with `BigDecimal` as `double` if you know what you are doing.  Sadly understanding floating point is too rare a skill.

Answer (score 2):

There are four methods to convert the object from what you really want: `intValue`, `longValue`, `floatValue` and `doubleValue`. Just choose the one that best fit for you and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice the Reference types for primitives all implement methods like `intValue()` (they're all pretty much implemented the same way) which are abstract on the `Number` interface. (

For example, `Integer` (which extends `Number`) has

```
/**
 * Returns the value of this {@code Integer} as a
 * {@code long}.
 */
public long longValue() {
    return (long)value;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of this {@code Integer} as a
 * {@code float}.
 */
public float floatValue() {
    return (float)value;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of this {@code Integer} as a
 * {@code double}.
 */
public double doubleValue() {
    return (double)value;
}
```

So when you have a reference to a `Number`, you can do

```
Number n = ...;
int value = n.intValue();
```

it will polymorphically call the dynamic type's method.

You can always check the type of `Number` and cast then

```
Number n = ...;
if (n instanceof Integer) 
    Integer i = (Integer) n;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Number` is the super class of many other classes in Java used to declare "number" types. It is used mainly in Generics and when you need to use reference of super class in `Collections` in order to exploit polymorphism:

```
class A<T extends Number>{
}
```

or

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Integer("1"));
list.add(new Double("1.1"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Number n = library.function();
   int i = n.intValue();
   System.out.print(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast it to `int`, but you can cast it to `Integer` (assuming it's a reference to an `Integer`) (and `Integer` is just a wrapper class for `int`, Java uses [unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) which allows you to essentially use `Integer` as an `int`).

Doesn't work:

```
Number n = 3;
System.out.println(3 + (int)n);
```

Works:

```
// autoboxing int(3) to Integer(3) and creating a reference of type Number to it
Number n = 3;

// unboxing Integer(3) to int(3) and adding it to int(2)
System.out.println(2 + (Integer)n);
```

As cHao mentioned, you'll get a `ClassCastException` if the `Number` doesn't reference an `Integer` (it can, for example, also reference a `Double`). To avoid this, you can check
`if (n instanceof Integer)` prior to trying to cast.

Or you can use the `xxxValue` functions as suggested in some of the other answers (this should prevent the need to check what it's an instance of, as all classes need to implement all `xxxValue` functions (as they are `abstract` in `Number`), although these could theoretically be implemented to throw exceptions, although I doubt any classes in the standard API would do this).

**The reason I suggested casting** above the `xxxValue` functions is because this makes what type you want explicit, as opposed to just happily returning you a value of a different type, although it may not be what you want. Consider this example:

```
Number n = 3.9999999; // that's rather close to 4

// prints '3' as double to int conversion rounds down
System.out.println(n.intValue());

// returns false
if (n instanceof Integer)
  // would've thrown exception
  System.out.println((Integer)n);
else
  // prints '3.9999999 is not an integer! It is a Double'
  System.out.println(n + " is not an integer!! It is a " + n.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: Casting to `Integer` only works if you know that you were indeed given an `Integer`.  Were you to say `Number n = 3.0;` instead, i'm about 94% certain you'd end up with a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: @cHao True, added a note.

Comment: All standard subclasses of `Number` implement `xxxValue` in a useful way, so it's safe to rely on.  The one huge caveat is that they will basically shoehorn the number's value into whatever type you ask for, lopping off high bits and/or rounding/truncating as needed to do so.  What you get back may not resemble the actual value.